GitHub action chaosaffe/split-tests cannot be download in private project
I developed a sample GitHub workflow where I split the tests to be executed in parallel using multiple jobs. The splitting of the tests to chunks is performed by the chaosaffe/split-tests github action. The sample project is inside my own GitHub account as a public repo.
I want to put the developed workflow into a private GitHub project. The private project cannot found the chaosaffe/split-tests github action during the workflow is ran. I guess there is some permission issue.
Can anybody share what I need to configure in the private project so the chaosaffe/split-tests github action will be available to be download?
The log of the runner:
Current runner version: '2.319.1'
Operating System
Runner Image
Runner Image Provisioner
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
Secret source: Actions
Prepare workflow directory
Prepare all required actions
Getting action download info
Error: Unable to resolve action. Repository not found: chaosaffe/split-tests


I noticed that the split-tests action has different references in the GitHub Marketplace. The example on the Marketplace page uses the following reference:'chaosaffe/split-tests@v1-alpha.1'
   'chaosaffe/split-tests@v1-alpha.1' 

However, when I click the 'Use latest version' button, it suggests a different path:
   'uses: scruplelesswizard/split-tests@v1-alpha.1'

It seems like the correct one is the latter 'uses: scruplelesswizard/split-tests@v1-alpha.1'
What’s strange is that in another repository, I can use the reference from the example 'chaosaffe/split-tests@v1-alpha.1' without any issues. Here's the repo for reference.

Under your private repo Setting in the side menu Action -> General set Actions Permissions to allow use of third party actions.
